# Confused on how to approach this (writing a function, returning a string)

Tags: javascript, function

So I have to write a function plusLettuce that accepts one parameter as an argument and the function has to return a string that has my argument and the phrase "plus lettuce". So I'm guessing if I type in plusLettuce("Onions"); into my console I should get "Onions plus lettuce" as my output.

This is what I have so far .. so I wrote my function with a parameter and I'm confused what to do next. (I'm a total noon sorry) Do I  make a variable word? I'm just stuck on what my next step has to be. Please help.

```
var plusLettuce = function(word) {
   var word = 
}
```

Comment: If you're learning Javascript, I really recommend the book "Javascript: The Good Parts" (O'Reilly collection). This will help you learn it the right way. :)

Comment: @PauloAvelar that book is aimed at people who already know it.

Comment: The whole book, yes. But I wish I'd read it before learning a lot of wrong stuff. This is the kind of book you should read a first time and get 20% out of it, then read it again a year later and fill a lot of gaps. It may be really advanced, but the language and the line of thought is very straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [addition operator `+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) to concatenate strings, and the [`return` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.9) to return the result of the function call:

```
var plusLettuce = function(word) {
   return word + " plus lettuce";
};
plusLettuce("Onions"); // "Onions plus lettuce"
```

Comment: Could also use `word.slice( -1 )` or `word[ word.length - 1 ]` to check for a space at the end of the input and conditionally apply that leading space. Obviously not part of the question, but I figure it's good to be proactive?

Comment: @rockerest Yes, or also `word.trim() + " plus lettuce"`.

Answer (score 2):

JS uses `+` for string concatenation.
You're also overwriting your `word` (which is already there, in your function), when you declare a new `var word`.

So

```
function plusLettuce (phrase) {
  // I don't say `var phrase`, because it already exists
  var phrasePlusLettuce = phrase + " plus lettuce"; // note the space at the start
  return phrasePlusLettuce;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you give a function a parameter, it automatically becomes a local variable for that function. Meaning that you can immediately use it as a variable too.

```
var plusLettuce = function(word) { // I take the var word from here...
   return word + ' plus lettuce'; // ...and then use it here.
};
console.log(plusLettuce('Onions')); // This is where I assign the var word.
```

So what's happening here is that I'm telling the plusLettuce function to return whatever the user gave as a parameter plus ' plus lettuce'. Then call it in the console.log();

Answer (score 0):

In programming this is called string concatenation, what your been asked to do is make a static string concatenate with a dynamic one.

```
function plusLettuce (phrase){
  var staticWord = ' plus lettuce';
  return phrase + staticWord
}
console.log(plusLettuce('Onions'))
```

Remember that a parameter/argument is a variable accessible by the function only, the static part meaning it will always be the same can be a assign to a variable to keep the code clean. and the dynamic part which is the parameter will be different every time according to what is passed on to the function each time is called.